# jquery how can i rewrite this code in a more optimized way

Tags: jquery, optimization

What is the best way to optimize the following so i have a shorter code.

```
$('#font').live('click', function(){
        var z = $(elmid).css('z-index');
        $('#editorWrapperOuter').css('z-index',(parseInt(z)+1));
        $('#fontTypeBox').show();
});
$('#fontSize').live('click', function(){
        var z = $(elmid).css('z-index');
        $('#editorWrapperOuter').css('z-index',(parseInt(z)+1));
        $('#fontSizeBox').show();
});
$('#fontHeader').live('click', function(){
        var z = $(elmid).css('z-index');
        $('#editorWrapperOuter').css('z-index',(parseInt(z)+1));
        $('#fontHeaderBox').show();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can change the `font` ID to `fontType`, do this:

```
$('#font,#fontSize,#fontHeader').live('click', function(){
        var z = $(elmid).css('z-index');
        $('#editorWrapperOuter').css('z-index',(parseInt(z)+1));
        $('#' + this.id + 'Box').show();
});
```

Same code, except that it uses the [`multiple-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) to select all three at the same time.

If you can't change that ID, then do this:

```
$('#font,#fontSize,#fontHeader').live('click', function(){
        var theID = this.id === "font" ? "fontType" : this.id;
        var z = $(elmid).css('z-index');
        $('#editorWrapperOuter').css('z-index',(parseInt(z)+1));
        $('#' + theID + 'Box').show();
});
```

Comment: The last line of every portion also contains a different id. You missed that.

Comment: @alex: Yes I did. Can you change the `font` id to `fontType`? If so, It'll be simple.

Comment: @alex: I updated assuming you can change that ID. If not, we can still do it, but the consistency will make things much simpler.

Comment: the show() id's are not the same as the selectors ids. So this.id is not right. It's referring to the id's clicked on and not the id's of the boxes we want to show.

Comment: @alex: Nope. Look again. It is concatenating `"Box"` onto the ID.

Comment: Perfect. I changed font to fontType, Removed var theID and changed theID to this.id. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

Either abstract this portion of code out to a separate function,

```
var foo = function() {
var z = $(elmid).css('z-index');
$('#editorWrapperOuter').css('z-index',(parseInt(z)+1));
$('#fontHeaderBox').show();
};
```

or create a jQuery array of these objects as follows:-

```
$('#font, #fontSize, #fontHeader').live('click', function(){
    var z = $(elmid).css('z-index');
    $('#editorWrapperOuter').css('z-index',(parseInt(z)+1));
    $('#fontHeaderBox').show();
});
```

Hopefully the syntax is right.

Comment: Your overlooking that the last line of every portion have a different id